# Queuing multiple task_struct structures?

Tags: linux, process, synchronization, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I would like to queue up multiple `struct task_struct`s in my block device driver. Here, each `task_struct` would correspond to a userlevel thread which uses the `ioctl()` system call to send a userspace buffer to my block device driver. Once I queue up multiple `task_struct`s, I would like to keep them on the queue until a particular condition is met (i.e., the buffer has been written down to the disk).

So, my question is, how do I queue up multiple `task_struct`s, put them to sleep, and then wake a subset of the queued `task_struct`s when some condition is met?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `kthread_create` as many times as you want to create new threads, and then call `wake_up` on whatever subset of threads you want.

Comment: I'm not creating any kernel threads. Userland threads call `ioctl()`. I want to block the call to `ioctl()` made by each thread. Since simultaneous calls will be made to the `ioctl()` by multiple threads, I want to queue up the `task_struct` corresponding to each of these userland threads and call some form of interruptable sleep. Once a condition is met, I want to wake up these threads (at least a subset of them). I hope this makes my question more clear?

Comment: Sure, each of the user threads enters your `ioctl` function, and you can have them go to sleep with `wait_event_interruptible()` or whatever.  Have each invocation of `ioctl` allocate whatever context you want to keep (or allocate some context per file, or whatever), stick it on whatever internal queue you want (create a list and `list_add` them, or any way you want to implement it), and then call `wake_up` for each user context as it becomes ready.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Roland! The next issue is the _context_ itself. In my code, multiple 256 byte buffers are merged into a single 4KB page. Multiple such 4KB pages are made part of a single `struct bio` (up to a max of 8 4KB pages) and then submitted to the disk. Once this BIO has been serviced, I need to wake up **all** those `task_struct`s which contributed 256 bytes towards the BIO. So, how do I keep track of which threads I need to wake up as there might many more threads being queued up simultaneously.

Comment: You need to design your data structures appropriately, so that you have a list or array or whatever that keeps track of what contexts are related to each IO.